# Samsung HDD has been stopped detecting

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, bios

2 days back when I start my Samsung Laptop (2.5years old), it's just showing up the Samsung Start Up screen and stuck.

It's not allowing me to enter into BIOS. Upon asking in a local service center, I got to know that the HARD DISK is damaged. So I tried to start my laptop with my friends HDD and it worked.

Being confirmed about the HDD damage, I tried to use it as external as I had an internal to external converter (Thanks to Segate BackUp Plus). First I got the windows sound of adding external drive and the LED get on. I was happy. But after a few second, the same sound struck and the LED start blinking continuously. In the whole process, my HDD didn't get detected for a second.

Now I have few queries/concern:
1. Is it possible to repair my HDD with out removing data?
2. If YES, what could be it's probable cost?
3. If NO, how can I recover data in home?

Comment: Honestly, if the hard drive is corrupt, take everything off it and bin it! But are you saying you attach corrupt hard drive as external but Windows only sees it for a short time?

Comment: In this situation, I don't think there's anything you can do short of sending it to a professional drive recovery place, but that's not cheap.

Answer (score 0):

you can check your HDD with pareted magick & analyze SMART data of your 
HDD and find if your HDD is failing.if your HDD is failing better you try to recover
any data that recides on your dieing HDD.(N.B:this may accelerate the process of damaging the disk.)you can use the extended guide from HTG 
on recovering data from HDD via this [LINK](http://www.howtogeek.com/169344/how-to-recover-a-deleted-file-the-ultimate-guide/)
if the data is of very much importance better you send them to any professional recovery
services.but chances are, they may charge you even if they didn't recover anything.
remember,this is not cheap.if you want your data badly , use this method.
i think it's a bad idea trying to repair this HDD of yours from your descriptions.
better you buy a new one.magic doesn't work with electronics